# There should be only two results, but why is it repeated three times?

Tags: sql

```
select a.m_num,a.filename,a.title,a.price,a.stock
from newboard a , cart b
where a.m_num = b.m_num and a.board_num = ANY(select board_num from cart where m_num = '82');
```

The result

| FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELD4 | FIELD5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 82 | NO1.png | car | 39000 | 1 |
| 82 |  |  | 0 | 0 |
| 82 | NO1.png | car | 39000 | 1 |
| 82 |  |  | 0 | 0 |
| 82 | NO1.png | car | 39000 | 1 |

Why is it repeating?

Comment: in where ,second condition you should add distinct to board_num. provide data to better replaying your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since inner join is working as Cartesian Product. To get distinct rows either use distinct keyword after select or use group by.

Example:

```
select a.m_num,a.filename,a.title,a.price,a.stock
from newboard a , cart b
where a.m_num = b.m_num 
and a.board_num = ANY(select board_num from cart where m_num = '82')
 group by a.m_num,a.filename,a.title,a.price,a.stock;
```